# Props change (redux) resets the local state when using useState - updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am rewriting my class components into functional components. One component uses both Redux and local-state and I noticed that every time the props (redux state) change, the `useState` hook is executed, resetting my local state. Is this expected behavior, and how to persist your local-state?

old (simplified)

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }
```

new

```
// Count gets reset to 0 every time reduxState changes
const MyComponent = ({reduxState}) => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
```

UPDATE - the cause of the problem is not in the refactoring into functional components. I have a parent (Higher Order Component) that re-creates the wrapped component on changes to Redux state. For clarity, here is the somewhat simplified HOC

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { fetchObject } from '../actions/objects'
import { fetchIfNeeded } from '../utils'

const withObject = ({element}) => WrappedComponent => ({id, ...rest}) => {
  const Fetcher = ({status, object, fetchObject}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchIfNeeded(
        status,
        ()=>fetchObject(element, id),
      )
    })

    // THIS SECTION IS THE CAUSE OF MY PROBLEM
    // Handle loading and error status
    if (status && status.error) return <>error loading: {status.error.message}</>
    if (status === undefined || object === undefined || status.isFetching) return <>loading</>
    // END OF SECTION

    // Pass through the id for immediate access
    return <WrappedComponent {...{object, status, id}} {...rest} />
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    object: state.data[element][id],
    status: state.objects[element][id]
  })

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchObject
  }

  const WithConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Fetcher)
  return <WithConnect/>
}

export default withObject
```

UPDATE2: The code sample above has been updated to highlight the problematic section. Every time the status changes (e.g. `isFetching: true`), the hoc returned a different component to reflect this. When it changes again to `isFetching: false`, a **new** instance of wrapped component is created and returned, losing its original state.

In short, it is a bad idea to return different components from a HOC depending on redux state. This should be handled in the regular component.

Comment: `useState` does not reset local state(`count`) on each render but only on initial one. So once you experience that it means your component is recreated instead of being updated. There are plenty reasons possible for component to be recreated but all those will lead to the same results whenever it's functional or class-based component. So 1) reason is outside `MyComponent` 2) reason is not related to functional nature of component.  Probably more code may give more insights. And check other changes you did in parent component.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. I will try and pinpoint the source.

Comment: @skyboyer - As you stated, the problem was in the parent, namely a HOC that provides redux data. I posted the relevant code in an answer. Any idea how to prevent re-creation of the component here?

Comment: try with splitting that into 2 HOCs. I guess it may be because of `Fetcher` is re-declared on each render so React during reconciliation decides to recreate this element instead of updating(constructor differs by its reference).

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks so far, I will dig deeper into the HOC

Comment: @skyboyer I updated the question to pinpoint the mistake I made

Comment: better make an official answer and confirm it. it's good way to help someone reaching here with Search. otherwise people may not reading down to Update2 or even don't open question from search results due to "Answers: 0"