# react hook cant perform setstate in an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

```
const SideAd = () => {
    const [sideAd, setSideAd] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
            query()
    }, [])
    const query = async () => {
        const res = await getSideAd()
        Array.isArray(res) && setSideAd(res)
    }
    return (
        <div className="sideAdComponent">   
        </div>
    )
}
```

I just want make a request at mounted and then set a new state. But instead I got error `react hook cant perform setstate in an unmounted component`

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things you may do here.

First is fighting race conditions in `useEffect` with using cleanup function(return value in `useEffect`'s callback)

```
const SideAd = () => {
    const [sideAd, setSideAd] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      const isMounted = true;
      getSideAd().then(res => Array.isArray && isMounted && setSideAd(res))
      return () => {isMounted = false;}
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="sideAdComponent">   
        </div>
    )
}
```

Check [nice article at hackernoon](https://medium.com/hackernoon/avoiding-race-conditions-when-fetching-data-with-react-hooks-220d6fd0f663) for more detailed explanation. To my mind this approach is even better then cancelling request(because it does not require you modify requester's code).

Another thing: maybe it's better to check for a reason why your component unmounted before response comes. Probably there is legit reason for that(say, you've navigated away while response has not come yet).

But it's also possible there is some HOC that declares component constructor inline and that causes all subtree to be re-created instead of updating. So it's worth spending some time on investigation - because there may be hidden bugs you have not found yet([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047447/props-change-redux-resets-the-local-state-when-using-usestate-updated#comment102675327_58047447)).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom hook called useIsMounted:

```
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => isMounted.current = false;
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};

const SideAd = () => {
  const [sideAd, setSideAd] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    query();
  }, []);
  const mounted = useIsMounted();
  const query = async () => {
    const res = await getSideAd();
    Array.isArray(res) && mounted.current && setSideAd(res);
  };
  return <div className="sideAdComponent"></div>;
};
```